# Java Invalid length 26 in local variable Table

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am so new I don't know anything. I downloaded IntelliJ and tried to run the most basic Hello World! program. It wont compile because of this error:

Error:java: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid length 26 in LocalVariableTable in class file com/sun/tools/javac/code/Types$TypeProjection

I'm guessing it is a setting or something since this is my first use of the program? Help very much appreciated!

Code:
package com.gohooljava.com;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   System.out.println("Hello World - Java!!");


}
```

}

Comment: Please put in the code you tried and failed. Else we cannot help you.

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: Possibly related?: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=263895

Comment: What JDK do you use to build project?

Comment: I used javac 11 and then I tried to down load 10 and run it again guessing it might have had something to do with it but it still came up.

Comment: It looks like your JDK installation has gotten corrupted in some way. Try reinstalling. This can also happen when your hardware (e.g. harddisk) is failing, so maybe try it on another computer? Good luck.

Comment: I have tried both 10 and 11 JDKs. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the program. I'm not sure how I would check a hard disk failure beings all of my other programs are running. I did find this article https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/jdk7-docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/upgrade-guide/article-01.html which I believe has my answer but I know so little about this stuff still that I don't know to use this information to fix my problem.